# Does $\lim |a_n-b_n|=0$ imply $\lim |f(a_n)-f(b_n)|=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ a continuous function and $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ two sequences with values in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $\lim |a_n-b_n|=0$. Does this imply $$\lim |f(a_n)-f(b_n)|=0?$$
Hint: the sequences $a,b$ needn't to be convergent.

Althoug I know this statements holds for uniformly continuous functions, I think it is not true for continuous functions generally. But no counterexample comes into my mind. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: note that $|\cdot|$ is continuous, Hence if $a_n$ and $b_n$ is convergent, claim holds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $a_n=\ln(n+1)$, $b_n=\ln(n)$. Then $|a_n-b_n|=\ln(1+1/n)\to 0$, but with $f(x)=e^x$ we find $|f(a_n)-f(b_n)|=1 \to 1$

Answer (score 5):

Take $f:x\mapsto x^2$, and for $n\ge 1$ have  $a_n=n+\frac{1}{n}$
and
 $b_n=n$.

Then $|a_n-b_n|=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ but $|f(a_n)-f(b_n)|=2+\frac{1}{n^2}\to 2$.